# Are negative lookbehinds supported in Impala?

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, regex-lookarounds, impala

I am using regexp_like in Impala with a negative lookbehind to find a pattern in a string array. I've built the expression as follows against a sample data set.
Running it yields the following error message.

> Invalid regex expression: '(?<=Hello).+'

`regexp_like(string_field,'(?<!Hello).+')`

| result | string_field |
| --- | --- |
| no match | Hello World, Bye World |
| match | Cool, Not Cool |
| no match | Cool, Hello, Bye Bye |

This negative lookbehind works in python. Has anyone else come across this? I've tried looking at the documentation but didn't find anything particularly useful.

A better example.

I am trying to find at least one occurrence from a comma separated string array in which at least one of the array elements is not preceded by the keyword e.g. - ('Hello'). A negative lookaround seems like one of the most elegant solutions for the task at hand.

Comment: RE2 regex library does not support lookarounds. Seems you do not need it, you may use something like `NOT LIKE '%Hello%'`

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example. Essentially, I am trying to find at least one occurrence from a comma separated string array in which at least one of the array elements is not preceded by the keyword e.g. ('Hello').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little clunky, but this works:

```
regexp_like(string_field, '(^|,)([^H]|H[^e]|He[^l]|Hel[^l]|Hell[^o])')
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/7mH6W5de8Ro7SB).